# Parsing replace quotes

Tags: python, regex, parsing, nlp, quotes

I'm trying to parse a text file to do some statistics about it in python. To do so, I want to replace some punctuations by tokens. One example of such a token would be all the punctuations who terminate a sentence(`.!?` become `<EndS>`). I managed to do this using a regex. Now I'm trying to parse quotes. therefore, I think, I need a way to distinguish opening quotes and closing quotes. I'm reading the input file line by line and I have no guarantee that the quotes will be equilibrated.

As example:

```
 "Death to the traitors!" cried the exasperated burghers.
 "Go along with you," growled the officer, "you always cry the same thing over again. It is very tiresome."
```

should become something like:

```
 [Open] Death to the traitors! [Close] cried the exasperated burghers.
 [Open] Go along with you, [Close] growled the officer, [Open] you always cry the same thing over again. It is very tiresome. [Close]
```

Is it possible to do this using regexes? Is there an easier/better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **sub** method (module re):

```
import re

def replace_dbquote(render):
    return '[OPEN]' + render.group(0).replace('"', '') + '[CLOSE]'

string = '"Death to the traitors!" cried the exasperated burghers. "Go along with you", growled the officer.'
parser = re.sub('"[^"]*"', replace_dbquote, string)

print(parser)
```

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.sub